# Not able to provide application dependency using dagger 2.16

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I am trying to implement dagger 2.16. First  of all the documents are really bad and I am struggling to get the app running. Currently I am trying to inject the room database to my viewmodel (android architecture component). But I am need of Context object with the new Dagger 2 version I am finding it hard. Can some one help me in this regard as How can I inject the application to provide the context

Comment: Try version 2.17. If even it doesn't restart Android studio.

Comment: The problem is it is not clear as where I have to define the application injection.I have included this line in my component @Binds
    fun provideContext(application: PlaceFinderApp): Application

Comment: https://github.com/umangburman/Dagger2-Android-Efficient-Approach This is my repository for Dagger2 Approach. It might help you.

Comment: Did it help...?

Comment: Could you edit your question with a basic sample of your code and errors you're getting?

Comment: @UmangBurman yes it helped in using proper syntax. Thanks

Comment: @NitinMesta Ah, I'm glad to hear that.